# How to send data from thread inside a ViewModel to main Activity/Fragment?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, viewmodel, android-livedata

Is there a way to send data from a thread inside a ViewModel to the main Activity/Fragment?

I'm building an app for financial chart and I'm taking data from an API, so in order to do that I need to put the API call in a thread. Apart from that I do some more calculations in order to represent the chart so I figured using a ViewModel.

Comment: In Java, use `MutableLiveData`. In Kotlin, use coroutines and a `StateFlow`. Each would be held by the `ViewModel` and observed by the activity/fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can update such `LiveData` (`MutableLiveData` or `MediatorLiveData`) values from a sub-thread by `postValue` method rather than `setValue` method.

And from Activity/Fragment, you can observe the `LiveData` of your `ViewModel` in general ways.